# Push Notification background issue in android 10

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing push notification in my app using firebase cloud function.But background service is not running in android 10 and that's why i am not receiving notification.

This is code in firebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    showNotification.showNotificationToAdmin(remoteMessage,this);
}
```

}

And this is code in manifest file

```
       <service
        android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessaging"
        android:exported="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: which device are you running your application on? in my case, i was debugging on huawei phone which does not have any google services which in result did not work with firebase notification. Changing to samsung worked fine for me

Comment: I m running on infinix

Comment: can you please put a log under 'onMessageReceived(Remote remoteMessage) and check whether it gets executed or not? like this->                                                
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

Comment: no,log cat dont show output when app gets killed

Comment: Add dependency in the app-level Gradle file implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-directboot:20.2.0'
Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive